# artisan make:migration ignores subfolders?

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 5.6 and and migration files inside `database/migrations/` work when I call `artisan migrate` but migration files in subfolders like `database/migrations/example` are skipped.

Even `artisan migrate:status` does not show the subfolders.

How can I tell Laravel to also include migration files from subfolders?

Comment: if you need to migrate all folders in migrations folder use `php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/*`

Comment: @STA `--path=/database/migrations/*` will only trigger migrations in subfolders. In other Laravelapplication that I have, migrations from subfolders are always fetched and executed in correct order (by filename). I thought its maybe a setting issue.

Comment: Maybe create a custom command that will run migrations on all the folders/sub folders? also https://stackoverflow.com/a/21643259/11801683

Comment: Never done this, but make sure you don't accidentally end up with two migrations with the same name, i.e. `2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table`, not sure how this will be handled when inserting migration names to the migrations table.

Comment: @jewishmoses your right. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43791121/2311074 is what I had in my other Laravel installation, that was why it worked there without problems :)

Answer (score 2):

> vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator.php line 465

same line number since Laravel 5.7 I guess, there's this line:

```
return Str::endsWith($path, '.php') ? [$path] : $this->files->glob($path.'/*_*.php');
```

This looks for the root migrations path matching the `*_*.php` pattern. If it was `**/*_*.php` you would've accomplished what you wanted.

---

But, good news! It can be hacked! The method responsible for getting the paths:

> vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\BaseCommand.php line 19

says that the path argument you gave to the command, will not be sanitized, or modified,

```
    if ($this->input->hasOption('path') && $this->option('path')) {
        return collect($this->option('path'))->map(function ($path) {
            return ! $this->usingRealPath()
                            ? $this->laravel->basePath().'/'.$path
                            : $path;
        })->all();
    }
```

So, setting the `path` argument as `database/migrations/**` should enable you to recurse into subfolders.

```
php artisan migrate --path="database/migrations/**"
```

Note: Then, for every `migrate[:*]` command to work, you need to specify the `--path` attribute. I migrated and rolled back with the `--path` attribute, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

There's a method in ServiceProvider that can do that for you.

```
loadMigrationsFrom($paths)
```

You will need to call it in your `AppServiceProvider`  in the boot method like so:

```
public function boot()
{
    $paths = [your, custom, migration, directories];
    $this->loadMigrationsFrom($paths);
}
```

After doing this, running `php artisan migtate` will take subdirectories in consideration.